# Center display:block links with CSS float left

Tags: php, html, css, center

I have a small DIV with `text-align:center`. All it's contents must be centered. In this DIV I have a PHP code that generates a certain number of A HREF links with `display:block`. I want all these links to stand next to one another (till it's too wide for the div, then the need to jump to the next line) so I use `float:left`. However, if only two links (blocks) show up, they are aligned left in my DIV, instead of in the middle. So I want my links to show up next to each other, but I also want to center them inside my DIV. How do I do this?

CODE per request:

```
<div style="margin-left:200px;width:300px;text-align:center;background-color:">Pagina's:<br clear="left"> 


<?php 
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(bedrijfsnaam) FROM profiles where plaats = '".$plaats2."'"; 
$rs_result = mysql_query($sql); 
$row = mysql_fetch_row($rs_result); 
$total_records = $row[0]; 
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / 1); 

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
            echo "<a style=\"float:left;display:block;color:white;width:22px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-size:20px;background-color:#483435;margin-left:4px\" href='".$plaatsnaam7.".php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 

}; 
?>


</div>
```

Comment: Please could you post the code.

Comment: Post the _generated_ HTML, not the PHP.

Comment: You're not required to accept answers that you don't want to, but you can always accept your own answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parent div must have

```
text-align: center
```

everything inside must have `display: inline; float: none;`

Comment: You're great, float:none fixed the issue!